# :hover not working

Tags: html, css, styles, hover

:hover is not working when applied to my styles:

http://jsfiddle.net/E9DXJ/

```
<nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid center">
        <div id="navcontainerimg" class="span12 center">
            <img src="img/hs-header.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="navcontainernav" class="span12 center">
            <span class="topleft">Our Story</span>
            <span class="topright">Awesome Support!</span>
            <span class="bottomleft">Read the Blog!</span>
            <span class="bottomright">Join Now</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes can be styled without the :hover, but when added it does nothing. If I click the :hover style display in chrome it will show it there, but not functional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you've set a negative `z-index` for the container so Chrome essentially won't recognise the hover events.

Change it to:

```
#navcontainernav    
{
    width: 720px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 170px;
    top: -233px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Or any other positive value.

Comment: Tom, that worked, but now it's creating another problem. I simplified the fiddle, but there's an image which goes inbetween those four corners. I got the hover to work by brining z-index>0 but if I bring the image above those it still doesn't work. Is there a way to do this without chopping up the image into two pieces (I imagine a rectangle with the circle separate might work) but I'd rather do it in CSS. http://healthysurprise.com/so

Comment: Hmm that's a tough one, what about changing your image so that it contains the proper clipping (e.g. http://cl.ly/N7pB - where the red border represents the image), then bringing the `z-index` of the nav higher than it?

Comment: That's possible?? :D You're amazing Tom. Now I have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Yep, just edit the image to include the green borders, then reduce the width of each nav element and reposition accordingly

Comment: Do you mean to chop up the image into pieces or is the their a css clipping property?

Comment: Check the image I posted, if you create an image using what's inside the red box you'll be able to use it without all the `z-index` issues

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25022/discussion-between-joseph-winke-and-tom-walters)

Answer (score 2):

change on #navcontainernav z-index: -5; to z-index: 1;

this works on all browsers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: sorry.. don't understand your answer.. the problem are the hovers! which will work by changing z-index